# Super/win key not working on Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows

I have both Linux and Windows systems on my machine. Everything was going ok, but yesterday my super/win key button stopped working after restarting the computer and changing in BIOS the fn key options (so that i didn't have to press it to use the functionality of f1..12). I tried to check it on Windows 10 OS but it didn't work.

Comment: Hello Igor, it would really help if you could produce some technical details. what keyboard is this ? What driver are you using? What operating system (name and version of linux) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you change the `fn` function back or has it stopped working completely, does it work on other computers and are you sure it is software related and not hardware?
What keyboard model, motherboard, bios revision and operating system versions / distros do you use?